# What does nm stand for?

Tags: linux, command-line, command, symbols

The linux command line program [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm), lists symbols from object files.
But what does nm actually stand for?

I couldn't find it anywhere in documentation.
Does it mean "name mangle"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "names" or "name list".

> Nm prints the name list (symbol table) of each object file in the argument list.

([V7 Unix manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nm&manpath=Unix%20Seventh%20Edition&format=ascii), 1979)

Comment: Always be careful with what two-letter command names "stand for."  For instance, dd stands for "convert and copy": they couldn't call it cc!  In school, I wrote a tool to scour the disk for all the links to a given file and report their names.  I couldn't call it ln (for linknames), so I chose kn.  that's how it is.

Comment: Understood that not all commands are abbreviations however this seems pretty obvious on this one. :)